# let$\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions on $[0,\infty)$ suth that $\vert {f_n (x)}\vert \le e^{-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, almost-everywhere

let$\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions on $[0,\infty)$ suth that $\vert {f_n (x)}\vert \le e^{-x}$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$. if $f_n \rightarrow 0 [a.e]$, then $f_n \rightarrow 0 [a.u] $

Comment: What does "a. u" mean?

Comment: I think almost uniformly

Comment: Welcome to MSE, but you should add some thoughts or other context to your question. Otherwise people might think you came here just to get a cheap and easy answer to a HW problem.

Comment: yes, almost uniformly

Comment: excuse me, i dont know it, i study real analysis Bruckner by myself. some problems are hard. excuse me. i'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\epsilon>0.$ Choose $M>0$ such that $e^{-x}<\epsilon$ on $[M,\infty).$ Use Egorov on $[0,M].$